# Switching to WiFi connection when Ethernet is slow (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ethernet, powerline-networking

My PC is connected to a powerline adapter via an Ethernet cable, and I get a fast connection. However several times a day the powerline adapters seem to lose connection for a couple of minutes, leaving me without internet. I also have WiFi, which I can use to connect the PC to the main router, at a lower speed, but it's much better than nothing.

If I physically disconnect the Ethernet cable, Windows switches instantly to the WiFi connection. However when the powerline adapter randomly disconnects from its buddies, Windows still sees itself as on Ethernet connection, and I lose internet.

So in order to maintain a constant connection, what I need is for Windows to automatically make use of the WiFi connection for internet when the Ethernet becomes slow / unresponsive to traffic. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Windows does not have this capability built in to it.

Comment: Windows 7 supports NIC teaming (bonding). Just connect both via ethernet and wifi, configure teaming and windows will automatically use the faster from those interfaces.

Comment: @Marki555 Thanks for the suggestion. It seems that NIC teaming is a feature specific to the hardware drivers or switch (and there are no such settings on mine). Most promising thing I've found is this script, which continuously checks utilization and adjusts the "Interface metric" that Windows uses to decide which NIC to use for a new connections: http://menistuff.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/network-load-balancing-using-windows-7.html If I could adapt it to choose the connection based on ping time, I think it would work. However I don't really speak VBS or understand Windows at a low level.